# Question regarding ROS(turtlesim).Moving one turtle towards another turtle

Tags: ros-melodic, turtlebot, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a python node such that it subscribes to relevant topics and publishes to relevant topics to make default 'turtle1' at (5.444,5.444) move towards a newly spawned turtle 'blah' at (X1, Y1) and stops at a 'D' unit distance from 'blah'.(This is in ROS)Can someone please explain or provide a solution?!

I gave new subscriber as `rospy.Subscriber('turtle/blah',Pose,update_posenew)`and a new object called as `posenew=Pose()` inside `__init__` function. The callback function is:

> ```
> def update_posenew(self,data)
> ```

> ```
>    self.posenew=data
> ```

> ```
>    self.posenew.x = round(self.pose.x, 4)
> ```

> ```
>    self.posenew.y = round(self.pose.y, 4)
> ```

... Uptil now fine.now.. In the move2goal function

> ```
>  def move2goal(self):
> ```

> ```
>      goal_pose =Pose()
> ```

> ```
>      goal_pose.x =∆
> ```

> ```
>      goal_pose.y = ∆
> ```

What should be given in place of ∆?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347213/question-regarding-ros(turtlesim).moving-one-turtle-towards-another-turtle/) by [Gun_Kan02](https://answers.ros.org/users/52746/gun_kan02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [this](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials/Go%20to%20Goal) is exactly what you are looking for. You just need to subscribe your `/blah/pose` to get the goal pose rather than get it from the user. 
 
As for

> stops at a 'D' unit distance from 'blah'

simply set  `distance_tolerance` to your D unit.

I hope this helps!

P.S. This question is not really related to `turtlebot`. I suggest you change the tag to `turtlesim`.

---

Edit:

You should add `self` to create your instance attribute so that  other methods in `TurtleBot` class are able to access `self.posenew` too. The topic you have subscribed to is incorrect. What is `turtle/blah`? It should be `spawn_name/pose`so in your case, i.e. `blah/pose`. The  callback – `update_posenew` where you update your `self.posenew` is also wrong. Notice that you have two turtles so you have two different poses. Therefore, you need to round the pose of your blah turtle not the turtle1's one. So simply make this change to your code.

```
self.posenew.x = round(self.posenew.x, 4)
self.posenew.y = round(self.posenew.y, 4)
```

∆.x and ∆.y are thus the updated `self.posenew.x` and `self.posenew.y` respectively.

```
goal_pose.x = self.posenew.x
goal_pose.y = self.posenew.y
```

Please also be aware that when you assign `Pose()` to your new instance attribute `self.posenew` inside `__init__`, the contents of `self.posenew` are initially all set to 0.0 which might affect the calculation of distance/velocity in `move2goal()`. So I advise you to add

```
rospy.wait_for_message('blah/pose', Pose)
```

after definition of `self.posenew` to wait for the message to arrive on the topic `blah/pose` or simply adding `rospy.sleep(0.5)` will do the trick.

---

Originally posted by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) with karma: 241 on 2020-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gun_Kan02](https://answers.ros.org/users/52746/gun_kan02/) on 2020-03-22**:
I understood that there is a need of /blah/pose subscriber but after that how to change the goal_pose to and how to update and callback and how to differentiate between blah and turtle1 subscriber?!

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-03-22**:
You can create another subscriber that subscribes to `/blah/pose` and has its own callback function. For more information, please take a look at [this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/61236/multiple-subscribers-in-one-cpp-file/). I am not sure what you want to achieve specifically. If you just want to make your `turtle1` move towards `blah` once instead of continuously chasing it. It's probably better to set the goal_pose once using [ros::topic::waitForMessage()](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html) than update it repeatedly through callback.

**Comment by [Gun_Kan02](https://answers.ros.org/users/52746/gun_kan02/) on 2020-03-22**:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials/Go%20to%20Goal.
I referred to this link and now I got stuck at one point. I created another subscriber and callback(update_posenew) for 'blah' turtle with topic /blah/pose.now in the move2goal function what should I equate goal_pose to(i mean what is the syntax) Can you please help?! This has been itching me for 2 days. Please!!

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-03-22**:
Can you please elaborate on that? At what point did you get stuck? I would like to know what you've assigned to your goal_pose.

**Comment by [Gun_Kan02](https://answers.ros.org/users/52746/gun_kan02/) on 2020-03-22**:
I gave new subscriber as rospy.Subscriber('turtle/blah',Pose,update_posenew)
And a new object called as
posenew=Pose() inside **init** function.
The callback function is:
def update_posenew(self,data)
self.posenew=data
self.posenew.x = round(self.pose.x, 4)
self.posenew.y = round(self.pose.y, 4)
...
Uptil now fine.now..
In the move2goal function

def move2goal(self):
goal_pose =Pose()
goal_pose.x =∆
goal_pose.y = ∆
What should be given in place of ∆?!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-22**:
@Gun_Kan02: could you please add these sort of updates (ie: the ones which contain code) to your main question text? Comments are too small.

Please *append* your current code to your original question. Use the `edit` button/link for that.

**Comment by [Gun_Kan02](https://answers.ros.org/users/52746/gun_kan02/) on 2020-03-22**:
someone please explain?!

**Comment by [Gun_Kan02](https://answers.ros.org/users/52746/gun_kan02/) on 2020-03-22**:
Yess this worked thank you so much tcchiang

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-03-23**:
I'm glad to be of help, @Gun_Kan02.

**Comment by [Suyashhchougule](https://answers.ros.org/users/61937/suyashhchougule/) on 2021-01-30**:
@Gun_khan what worked ? i am stuck at same problem . can you explain ?